# How to pass parameter from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am binding data in dropdownlist like bellow

```
     private void GetallAssociate()
      {
        var dsAssociate = AdminBL.Ins.selectAllAssociates();
        if (dsAssociate.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlAssociate.DataSource = dsAssociate;
            ddlAssociate.DataTextField = "AssociateName";
            ddlAssociate.DataValueField = "Associateid";
            ddlAssociate.DataBind();
            ddlAssociate.Items.Add("ALL");
            ddlAssociate.Items.Insert(0, "Select Associate");
        }
    }
```

IN this i am passing parameter(int) value as Associateid so when i am selecting ALL option that time getting error like can't convert string to int so what i am doing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code ,

```
ddlAssociate.Items.Add(new ListItem("All","customIDHere"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Blank space in first option. like this

```
ddlAssociate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Associate","")));
```

then check if the selected value is not blank the pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
  ddlAssociate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", -1));
```

This will add `All` at index `0` with value `-1`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a value to this list item,do it like this

> ddlAssociate.Items.Add(new ListItem("Name" , "Value"));

Answer (score 0):

The "ALL" is being set as a value when instead your dropdownlist is expecting an Int as a value. 
Change this 
`ddlAssociate.Items.Add("ALL");` 
to this 
`ddlAssociate.Items.Add(new ListItem("ALL", 0));`